# Using JPA Criteria Builder with table joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use the JPA Criteria Builder to join two tables, `Country` and `Geotarget`.
The equivalent `SQL` is

```
Select distinct Country.* from Country Inner Join Geotarget
 where Geotarget.Country_ID = Country.ID;
```

my code is

```
     CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder getTransactionalEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Country> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Country.class);
    Root<Country> root = criteriaQuery.from(Country.class);
    Join<Geotarget, Country> geotargetJoin = root.join(Geotarget_.country, JoinType.INNER);
    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(Country_.id,Geotarget_.country);
    criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    criteriaQuery.select(Country.class).distinct(true);
    return findAllObjects(criteriaQuery);
```

But is wrong, it doesn't even parse in places. In particular i can't seem to find the code for either the join line, or the equals cause which doesn't seem to like to compare two fields.
Can you help me, with the correct code.

Comment: Show the definition of the relevant properties of each entity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the predicate. The join itself should perform the GeoTarget.Country_ID = Country.ID. So revise to:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder getTransactionalEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Country> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Country.class);
Root<Country> root = criteriaQuery.from(Country.class);
Join<Geotarget, Country> geotargetJoin = root.join(Geotarget_.country); // Default is inner
criteriaQuery.select(Country.class).distinct(true);
return findAllObjects(criteriaQuery);
```

Comment: Where does the underscored name 'Geotarget_' come in, why I try these I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'Geotarget_'

Comment: The suffix underscore classes are from the JPA Metamodel. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html as an example.